# Applying Reflection to DropShadow Effect in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Using JavaFX, I am trying to draw text onto a canvas with a drop shadow and a reflection effect chained together.

The following code will display red text that is reflected, and then a drop shadow is applied to the original and reflected text.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400,400);
GraphicsContext context = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
context.setFont( new Font("Arial Bold", 48) );
context.setFill(Color.RED);
DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow(6, 2, 2, Color.BLACK);
Reflection reflect = new Reflection(10, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
shadow.setInput(reflect);
context.setEffect(shadow);
context.fillText("Hello, world!", 100,100);
```

However, the drop shadow appears "backwards" in the reflection, because the shadow needs to be applied first for a realistic effect. I tried to accomplish this by reversing the order in which the effects are applied, by changing the `setInput` and `setEffect` lines of code from above as follows:

```
reflect.setInput(shadow);
context.setEffect(reflect);
```

However, the result is that only the reflection is applied; I can not see any drop shadow at all.

Why isn't the drop shadow being applied / not visible?

How can I rewrite this code to achieve the desired effect (only using composition of effects, if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if what you say can be achieved by using `GraphicsContext` with standard API, so other answers are welcome. However, this might be a temporary workaround, provided that it is actually what you needed. The shadow is applied first and then the image is copied pixel by pixel to imitate the reflection effect. Please see the screenshot below: (original - on the left, new - on the right).

[image: Reflection]

Full working example is attached below. It requires some tweaking to get a general solution but there should be enough to start with.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.effect.Effect;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXApp extends Application {

    private Parent createContent() {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400,400);

        Font font = new Font("Arial Bold", 48);
        Color fill = Color.RED;
        DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow(6, 2, 2, Color.BLACK);

        fillTextWithReflection(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(), "Hello, world!", 100, 100, font, fill, shadow);

        return new Pane(canvas);
    }

    private void fillTextWithReflection(GraphicsContext g, String text, double textX, double textY, Font font, Color fill, Effect effect) {
        Text t = new Text(text);
        t.setFont(font);

        // 5 px margin
        Canvas tmpCanvas = new Canvas(t.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() + 5, t.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() + 5);

        // set configuration
        GraphicsContext tmpContext = tmpCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        tmpContext.setFont(font);
        tmpContext.setFill(fill);
        tmpContext.setEffect(effect);

        // draw on temporary context
        tmpContext.fillText(text, 0, font.getSize());

        // take a snapshot of the text
        WritableImage snapshot = tmpCanvas.snapshot(null, null);

        int w = (int)snapshot.getWidth();
        int h = (int)snapshot.getHeight();

        WritableImage reflected = new WritableImage(w, h);

        // make an 'inverted' copy
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            // imitate fading out of reflection
            double alpha = y / (h - 1.0);

            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                Color oldColor = snapshot.getPixelReader().getColor(x, y);
                Color newColor = Color.color(oldColor.getRed(), oldColor.getGreen(), oldColor.getBlue(), alpha);

                reflected.getPixelWriter().setColor(x, h - 1 - y, newColor);
            }
        }

        // draw on the actual context
        // images are drawn from x, y top-left but text is filled from x, y + h
        // hence corrections
        // this can be replaced with actual fillText() call if required
        g.drawImage(snapshot, textX, textY - font.getSize());
        g.drawImage(reflected, textX, textY + h - font.getSize());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- you've basically rewritten the image effect from scratch, it seems! However, I am mainly interested in why my code as given isn't working, and want to know if the desired effect can be achieved using only composition of effects. I've updated my question above to be more clear. But thanks for your effort all the same!